# Linux Ubuntu mono

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, mono

I'm trying to install absolute small package of mono for our app, which is .net 4.0 (console app) what package should i install?

Is there a console only package ? Or maybe some script for ubuntu that analyzes the application and installs only needed mono dlls.

Thank you!

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install mono-runtime
```

That will only install the standard runtime.

Comment: that is correct but it is only mono executable, with this i cannot run apps while it does not contain core libs...

Comment: Have you considered adding the libmono-corlib4.0-cil package as well?

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide on the Mono project website to create a [smaller mono install](http://www.mono-project.com/Small_footprint)

Comment: Yes it is, but i was wondering if there is a minimal package available for ubuntu... including core libs without XSP2,....... only pure .net stuff